# Zoom In and Out Browser in PAF?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I need to perform actions like Zoom In and Out using Pace Automation Framework. How to use PAF Tags using keyboard Keys?

Answer (score 0):

We can use robot Tag to Zoom In and Out Browser in pace automation framework
Example:-
Zoom out

```
<robot command="{press}:{control},{type}:-,{release}:{control}"></robot>
```

Zoom in

```
<robot command="{press}:{control},{type}:=,{release}:{control}"></robot>
```